# Unable to run python-webkit2png

Tags: python, screenshot

I have installed [python-webkit2png](https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png) manually (without using pip) on Ubuntu 16.04. When i start it to get screenshot I am getting following error:

```
 p@vm:~/piscr$ webkit2png https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1256381
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/bin/webkit2png", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('webkit2png==0.8.3', 'console_scripts', 'webkit2png')()
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2749, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2402, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2408, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/p/piscr/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/webkit2png-0.8.3-py3.5.egg/webkit2png/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebkitRenderer'
```

Comment: What is the code you are running to get the screenshot?

Comment: @user1767754 Here is the code:
 `webkit2png https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1256381`

Comment: @user1767754 Did you notice any problem with the code ?

Comment: How did you "install" `python-webkit2png` manually without `pip`? Did you run the [Manual installation via Git](https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png#manual-installation-via-git) and `setup.py`? The package has depends on `PyQt4` core features, which is built and compiled in C++. Do you have `PyQt4` installed (`python -m "PyQt4"`)?

Comment: I have installed all the prerequisites mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/adamn/python-webkit2png), Do I have still have to install `PyQt4` ?

Comment: Are you running it in a virtual environment?

Comment: @downshift Yes I am running under virtual environment

Comment: Installation Ubuntu
Add following packages: `apt-get install python-qt4 libqt4-webkit xvfb` <- you did this installation?

Comment: you don't need to install `PyQt4` manually, but yes you need `PyQt4` installed to use the `webkit2png` package. if you did follow the installation instructions in the documentation for Ubuntu installation (`apt-get install python-qt4`) then you should have `PyQt4` installed. `dpkg -s python-qt4` will tell you if it is installed.

Comment: Yes I executed this command and it installed everything successfully except `libqt4-webkit`. I was getting "E: Package 'libqt4-webkit' has no installation candidate". So I installed `libqtwebkit4` instead of `libqt4-webkit`

Comment: I executed `dpkg -s python-qt4` and found that `PyQt4` is installed

Comment: Ah, ok, did you **activate** your "virtual environment" before installing `python-qt4` or running your script? It looks like you haven't activated your virtual environment. When activated your prompt will show like: `(myvirtualenv_name) p@vm:~/piscr$`, but your prompt looks like the "normal" user environment prompt `p@vm:~/piscr$`

Comment: Yes I did that. I omitted some character while copying and pasting. Currently my prompt looks something like this `(env) p@vm:~/piscr`

Comment: I have tried it many times by creating a new virtual environment but the same problem persists. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159616/discussion-between-downshift-and-cody).

Comment: @Cody : was your issue resolved. I have the same issue now.